# Update a User Control from another User Control via AJAX

Tags: ajax, user-controls, telerik

Maybe I'm having a brain fart or something because it seems like this should be pretty simple but how do you update a User Control from another User Control via Ajax?

I have an ASPX page with two user controls and when I trigger a server-side event on one, I want to refresh a grid on the other so it'll update it's data.

I'm using Telerik controls if that helps.  Checkbox event on the first User Control causes the RadGrid in the second User Control to Rebind() and I have RadAjaxManager in the ASPX page and RadAjaxManagerProxy in the two User Controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for me `Page.DataBind()` doesn't work for me.

I declared in `UserControl`

```
// Declare a delegate
public delegate void save_CommandEventHandler ();

//Event
save_CommandEventHandler SaveViewChanged public event;

// I run SaveViewChanged() from a click_button but it can run from anywhere
protected void save_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateDataInDatabase();

    SaveViewChanged ();
}
```

In `page.aspx.cs` code

```
protected override void OnInit (EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit (e);

    // UserControle1 is the Id of your UserControl declared in Aspx Page
    UserControle1.SaveViewChanged + =
       New UserControle.save_CommandEventHandler
       (Save_CommandEventHandler);
}

private void save_CommandEventHandler () {
    // Reload the gridView gvExpence to see the change operated in the user control
    gvExpence.DataSource =DataAcces.getAllCompanyExpence ();
    gvExpence.DataBind ();

    // update user control 2
    usercontrol2.updateView();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An async callback will update the control that caused the postback and also any parent controls of its update panel.  If your datagrid is not being updated in the browser after an event it would suggest its update method is not being called

Try calling the .update method of the datagrids updatepanel in the checkbox event

Comment: Do you know where I can see an example of this implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the **ajaxRequest** or **ajaxRequestWithTarget** client-side methods of the AjaxManager to initiate an ajax call. More info about these methods can be found on the Telerik's online documentation: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/ajxclientsideapi.html